# ¿Por qué no puedo visualizar mi shape en la propiedad android:background de mi botón?

Tags: android, kotlin, botón, background, selector

Buen día a todos, tengo un problema con un shape creado y muestro a continuación.

Shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="@color/rojo"/>
    <corners android:radius="35dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/negroclaro"/>
</shape>
```

Y también mi selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_rectangle"></item>
</selector>
```

Entonces desde la propiedad background de mi button, cuando llamo a mi shape o al selector solo me dibuja el radio, pero no el mismo fondo del botón, además intente con el backgroundTint y tampoco funciona. He buscado soluciones en internet y he hecho lo mismo sin obtener lo que requiero.
Según la imagen que les muestro debería funcionar pero no tengo resultados.
Espero contar con su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí está el manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.academiamoviles.laboratorio04">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Laboratorio04">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el Manifest?

Comment: Sí, ya lo coloqué en la pregunta.

Comment: Puedes probar cambiando esta línea: 

`android:theme="@style/Theme.Laboratorio04"`

por: 

`android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`

Comment: Hola Franqo, he realizado el cambio pero sigue sin mostrarme el shape personalizado